# Profadol DE1303096 (B) wrong patent supplied

Tags: profadol

This is the patent for Profadol:

https://patents.google.com/patent/DE1303096B

However, when i redirect to espace I do not get a matching hit.

Comment: When I click on the Epacenet link it seems to work. It is an old document.

Comment: I'm assuming you got to DE1303096 via Wikipedia. However that article states Profadol was developed in the 1960's whereas D#1303096 seems to be from the early 1930s. Perhaps this document isn't the patent for Profadol and Wikipedia is in error.

Comment: This site might provide more useful information: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/profadol#section=Patents

Comment: I was able to get the joy. I found it in this patent:  DE1272296 (B) ― 1968-07-11